# X-Axis decimal places displayed using chartjs-plugin-zoom

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-plugin-zoom

When zooming in (both x&y set) the x-axis labels that are defaulted to 1 decimal place using Chart.config._config.options.scales.xAxis.ticks.precision = 1; will show 14 digits on the first and last tick mark whilst all other tick marks are 1 decimal place. Is there a setting to limit the first and last labels or, is this a bug?

[First & Last tick mark issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJXk0.png)

Using chartjs 4.3 I tried the following callback in the scales:xAxis:ticks: section.

```
callback: function(value) {
    if (Math.floor(value) === value) {
      return value;
    }
}
```

Which worked on line chart types but, no decimal places.
[Correct tick marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuT0g.png)

It did not work on time chart types (no tick marks were shown).
[Missing tick marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3ifB.png)

Comment: You may want to set, in your configuration object, `options.scales.xAxis.ticks.includeBounds: false`, see the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#linear-axis-specific-tick-options).

Comment: Also `Chart.config._config.options.scales.xAxis.ticks.precision = 1;` is funny; probably it's the chart instance, not `Chart` the class, which doesn't have a static `config` property; you may want to set that in the configuration object too, but its value is only used as an indication to compute the `stepSize`

Comment: The "options.scales.xAxis.ticks.includeBounds: false," has resolved the issue. Many thanks for your help.